# How can I redirect a string to replace the STDIN_FILENO file descriptor?

Tags: c++, bash

I'm currently trying to write my own bash shell, and input output redirection works fine, but I'm having trouble implementing "<<<".

For example, if I type `cat <<< "Hello world"`, it should display "Hello world".

For the other io redirectors like < and >, I've been using the open and dup system calls, but it won't work for this, unless I create a temporary text file.

Is there a way to do this without creating a temporary file?

I tried

```
int fd[2];
pipe(fd);
write(fd[1], string, strlen(string));
dup2(fd[1], 0);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [help] to learn about guidelines for posting questions here. This question is unclear/too broad. Explain the problem more directly, present your attempts to solve it and tell us in what way they've failed. Also, you ask "can I use them for this one" - which is really strange - why not just try it yourself?

Comment: Use `strace` to find out what `bash` is doing, or dive into the source code of [GNU `bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)

Comment: Open won't work unless I create a temp file with the string. I just wanted to know if there's a way to skip that step, and send it to stdin directly.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably creating a nameless pipe. See `man 3 pipe` for details. But basically this function will create two fds: one read-only, the other write-only. Whatever is written on one side it will be read on the other.

Then write the string to the writing end of the pipe, and install the reading end as the STDIN of the new process.

Comment: I used pipe for "|", but I'm not sure how I can use it here. I don't need to fork because I'm only calling execvp once right?

Comment: @KennethHuang: Well, you have to fork once or else you will lose the shell. But the easiest way would be to fork again and do as if `echo "Hello world" | cat`.